# Pandas - GroupBy - Transform a new column and reset Index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the below dataframe:

```
df = {'Type': [A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B],
'population': [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800],
'city_name': ['Chicago', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'New York']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

Type  city_name   population
A   Chicago      100
A   Chicago      200
A   Chicago      300
A   New York     400
B   Chicago      500
B   New York     600
B   Chicago      700
B   New York     800
```

I wish to add two new columns in df - **PopStd & PopC** on df grouped by Type and city_name. 
PopC will be calculated as count(population)-1
PopStd will be calculated as population.std() / sqrt(count(population))

Lastly I want only one record for each of the groups.

Now, I have been able to get the columns by:

```
df['PopC'] = df.groupby(['Type', 'city_name'])['population'].transform(lambda_fn_for_popC)
```

And a similar approach to get PopStd as well.

I just need to figure out how to get exactly one record for each group.

Comment: If you want a single value for each group, use agg instead of transform.

Comment: @ayhan-But I also want the columns Type and city name in the final dataframe. Also I want the aggregated columns to be added to df.

Comment: You can add `.reset_index()` at the end, it will add those as columns.

Comment: @ayhan-I added an 'as_index=False' parameter during the groupby operation. And it worked. Which I guess is equivalent to what you're saying

Comment: Yes it should do the same thing.